# "min()" com dois parâmetros

Tags: sql, parâmetros

A pessoa que trabalhou antes de mim na empresa fez esse código:

```
MIN(DATEPART('weekday',[Entrega Data Real]),6)
```

O que esse 6 significa?

Um `min()` pode ter dois parâmetros?

Comment: Qual SQL você está utilizando ? MYSQL? SQL server? Oracle?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

Não, não temos como saber o que ele significa, mas pelo código o resultado deve dar no máximo 6, ou seja, se o dia da semana for 7 (provavelmente domingo, depende da cultura usada) então ele considerará 6 (provavelmente sábado), mas se for quaisquer dias abaixo de 7, ele considerará o dia da semana da entrega.

Uma função [`min()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/min-transact-sql?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) precisa ter pelo menos dois argumentos já que ela resulta em um valor mínimo entre dois ou mais deles. Se tivesse só um argumento o resultado seria sempre ele mesmo.

Note que neste caso ela não está sendo usada como agregação e sim uma expressão simples, apenas pega o valor de uma coluna em uma linha e compara com o literal 6. Isto é feito linha a linha, mas não está procurando pelo mínimo de todas as linhas, como provavelmente está pensando. Ela só funciona para agregar se tiver alguma cláusula na *query* tiver algo que agrupe tudo. Nada postado indica isto e mesmo que seja usado assim a forma da função escrita não faria a agregação corretamente.